# Run 2 Python3 `http.server` on the same machine, different ports

Tags: python-3.x, basehttpserver

Situation: Need 2 ad-hoc Python3 `http.server` instances on the same computer.

Problem: The first server was started successfully on the command line

```
python3 -m http.server 8888
```

The second server was attempted with the following script:

```
import http.server
import socketserver as ss

os.chdir("/path/to/working/directory")
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
with ss.TCPServer(("", 8000), Handler) as httpd:
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except PermissionError:
        print("Permission denied.")
```

The second server terminated with `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use.`

Question: How can I run two Python3 `http.server` on the same machine (listening on `0.0.0.0`)?

Additional Information 1: I have checked, and there are no other services holding onto port `8888` (server 1's port), and `8000` (server 2's port).

Additional Information 2: I am not sure why, but if I reverse the two ports, both servers run as intended (i.e. server 1 runs on port `8000`; server 2 runs on `8888`). Any ideas why?

Comment: I tried this, it is working. You may need to change that second port number.

Comment: It was working with Additional Information 2. I just don't get why the original ports do not work.